# Rooting Android Galaxy S2 - Connection Error

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, rooting

I am trying to root my Galaxy S2.

So I followed instructions online, I booted in debug mode, connected the USB cable then pressed the up powerbutton to start the mode, I then opened up Odin v3 3.04 and it showed up with a device connected. I selected the correct .tar file under PDA and clicked start. It says "setup connection" and freezes at that.

I tried redoing it because it wasn't working. Eventually I decided to see if it was just the program. I opened Samsung Kies and it couldn't connect. It tried connecting for a long time and eventually just gave up.

The weird this is that when I plugin the USB cable my computer actually recognizes it as a Samsung Device because the first time I plugged it in it installed drivers automatically using Kies.

I tried using different USB ports, tried using a different cable and I tried charging it.

I couldn't tell if it was fully charged but it charged for 8 hours so I'm sure it was charged fully. Still didn't work.

After researching for 2 days and trying endlessly, I decided to see what you guys think.

So let me know if you have ideas! :)

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling kies, now it is connecting with Odin but it wont connect with kies at all. But its now showing this error.

```
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<ID:0/003> Odin v.3 engine (ID:3)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/003> zImage
<ID:0/003> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/003> 
<ID:0/003> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

Comment: You might have luck installing an aftermarket firmware, benefit: Android 4.3 with constant updates.Which model do you own? http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices#vendor="Samsung";

Comment: I know its the sliding one, but its with Rogers and that link doesn't list any Galaxy S2's with sliders. It also doesnt have a button, it has touch buttons with 4 at bottom if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this guide rooting mine:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1773659

I started at Step 1. HOW TO INSTALL TWRP OR CWM : ON STOCK FIRMWARE OR CUSTOM ROMS - GB, ICS AND JB

The guide even has a section for troubleshooting Odin errors.

Be careful with odin. When you're editing your bootloader. You can brick your device if you do it wrong, and then your only option is JTAG repair, which will cost you ~$50